# iOS openGLES1 glDrawArrays causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS on device only

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, 3d, exc-bad-access

I’m using OpenGLES1 for an augmented reality app.

In the app, I can move around and look at some 3d shapes drawn using some simple geometry methods:

```
void render()
{
    ....
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    drawCube(…);
    drawPyramid(…);
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        drawLine(0, i, 100, i);
    }
    ....
}
```

the methods works like this, with array of vertices:

```
void drawLine(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2) const
{
    const GLfloat line[] = {
        x1,y1,15,  //point A
        x2,y2,15  //point B
    };
    glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f); //line color
    glLineWidth(2.0f);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, line);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

My problem is that those methods work fine on the simulator but not on my phone5. Every time I call one of the 2 following low-level methods:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pyramidVertexFaces[i]);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
```

the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

If i remove those 3d shapes, the app works.

any idea why those methods works as expected on the simulator but crashes on the device?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if the use of const on that line[] puts it in some odd memory that openGL can't access properly while on a device.  It is a long shot though.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with const but maybe it's because he uses a local variable which will be destroyed before OpenGL will draw arrays

Comment: that was the sort of idea I had with whatever timing opengl has before it does the drawing.  Being const wouldn't really make any difference then.